# How do I resolve Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Select 
    c.name, c.number, f.Telephone3 As 'Phone Number', 
    (Select Value 
     from UserDefinedFieldLinks 
     where UserDefinedFieldID = 134) AS 'Referal Name',
    (Select Value 
     from UserDefinedFieldLinks 
     where UserDefinedFieldID = 135) AS 'Referal Acc No.', 
    (Select Value 
     from UserDefinedFieldLinks 
     where UserDefinedFieldID = 137) AS 'Referal Phone No.', 
    udl.value as Answer 
From 
    Customer C
Join 
    UserDefinedFieldLinks udl on udl.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
Join 
    UserDefinedFields d on udl.UserDefinedFieldID = d.UserDefinedFieldID
Join 
    UserDefinedFieldGroup e on d.UserDefinedFieldGroupID = e.UserDefinedFieldGroupID
Join 
    person f on C.CustomerID = f.PersonID
Where 
    e.UserDefinedFieldGroupID = 10
```

Comment: You modify the subquery with a condition or aggregate that limits the result to a single value ...  Currently more than 1 `Value` is returned from `UserDefinedFieldLinks` and the server does not know which one you want to use.

Comment: I need the values in all the three fields

Comment: Its unclear what you want, the 3 sub-queries are completely unrelated to the outer query, perhaps you mean to JOIN UserDefinedFieldLinks.

Comment: We understand you need all three fields. But at least one (probably all three) subquery is returning more than 1 row.

Comment: Try this query. "Select Value from UserDefinedFieldLinks where UserDefinedFieldID = 134" How many rows are returned?

Answer (score 0):

One of the below is returning more than one value, meaning UserDefinedFieldID is not unique:

```
(Select Value from UserDefinedFieldLinks where UserDefinedFieldID = 135)
(Select Value from UserDefinedFieldLinks where UserDefinedFieldID = 137)
```

If Value is duplicated for each UserDefinedFieldID (not normalised) then you could use:

```
(Select Max(Value) from UserDefinedFieldLinks where UserDefinedFieldID = 135)
```

Comment: I need the values for the three fields, using Max(Value) would only bring one.

Comment: Also, you would have to change the other subqueries:
(Select Max(Value) from UserDefinedFieldLinks where UserDefinedFieldID = 134)
(Select Max(Value) from UserDefinedFieldLinks where UserDefinedFieldID = 137)